# Static code analysis for chef cookbooks

Tags: chef-infra, rubocop

I am trying to use lint tools for my chef recipes. I am currently using foodcritic and rubocop. While using them for static code analysis it looks to me that foodcritic completely focuses on chef cookbooks but rubocop is mainly dealing with the ruby code and not particularly related to only chef. There are few rubocop offenses that I feel may not be applicable for chef recipes. I can forgo such by putting them in .rubocop.yml , however I am not too confident if those cops should be disabled or not .

Is there any standard or most acceptable set of cops that (a standard .rubocop.yml) which can be used for chef-cookbooks?

Comment: Why a -1? A comment would be helpful, dear down-voter!

Comment: This is opinion-based. The only direct answer is "no, there is no standard at this time".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at the cookbooks provided by *Chef* (formerly known as *Opscode*): https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/

The recently modified cookbooks use a *.rubocop.yml* like the following:

```yaml
AllCops:
  Includes:
    - Berksfile
    - Gemfile
    - Rakefile
    - Thorfile
    - Guardfile
  Excludes:
    - vendor/**

ClassLength:
  Enabled: false
Documentation:
  Enabled: false
Encoding:
  Enabled: false
HashSyntax:
  Enabled: false
LineLength:
  Enabled: false
MethodLength:
  Enabled: false
SignalException:
  Enabled: false
TrailingComma:
  Enabled: false
WordArray:
  Enabled: false
```

The current [ChefDK template](https://github.com/opscode/chef-dk/tree/master/lib/chef-dk/skeletons/code_generator) doesn't yet provide a *.rubocop.yml*